# Page Only Uploads One Image

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, file-upload

I'm creating a basic server that accepts `POST` and `GET` requests. I want to be able to upload images to a directory, but the date (location, name, description, id, etc.) to a JSON file. When I have a `GET` request, it collects the last part of the path (i.e. /upload?image=img1&image=img2), but in case of `POST` request, it only gathers the path to the upload (i.e. /admin/gallery). This makes it so that when I parse the header, it only grabs the last image that was submitted.

Since I'm posting to `/upload` I have a handler that parses the request and determines what kind of media it is and writes the contents to the file. Everything else works fine, but **I think it sees there are multiple objects with name "image"** and throws out everything but the last one.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="galleryForm" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="gallery">Picture File(s):</label> 
        <input name="image" type="file" multiple />         
        <input type="submit" value="Add Pictures" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="Title..." required  />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
if (req.body.image) {
    fs.writeFile(`public/media/images/${req.body.image.filename}`, req.body.image.data, function (err) {
        console.log(req.body.image);
        dataStore.create('gallery', {
            title: req.body.title,
            type: "image",
            description: req.body.description,
            images: ["public/media/images/" + req.body.image.filename]
        }, function (err, id) {
            res.statusCode = 303;
            res.statusMessage = "See Other";
            res.setHeader("Location", "admin/gallery.nsp");
            res.end();
        });
    });
}
```

My JSON file looks like this:

```
"6ed143c4-8493-448f-b3c3-d4e04cc5baaa":{
    "title":"Title...",
    "type":"image",
    "description":"Enter a description...",
    "images":[
        "public/media/images/img1.jpeg"
    ],
    "id":"6ed143c4-8493-448f-b3c3-d4e04cc5baaa"
}
```

But should end up looking like this:

```
"6ed143c4-8493-448f-b3c3-d4e04cc5baaa":{
    "title":"Title...",
    "type":"image",
    "description":"Enter a description...",
    "images":[
        "public/media/images/img1.jpeg",
        "public/media/images/img2.jpeg"
    ],
    "id":"6ed143c4-8493-448f-b3c3-d4e04cc5baaa"
}
```

Comment: I think you need to loop

Comment: Where would I put the loop? It's reading it somewhere since it's grabbing only the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You need add id at your input file. 
Refer my code below.

html example

```
<input name="image" id="my-input" type="file" multiple />
```

For jQuery-comfortable people, it's similarly easy

```
// assuming there is a file input with the ID `my-input`...
var files = $("#my-input")[0].files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
 alert(files[i].name);
}
```

For javascript example

```
// assuming there is a file input with the ID `my-input`...
var files = document.getElementById("my-input").files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
 alert(files[i].name);
}
```